# JavaScript conditional logic

Tags: javascript, logic

This gives me 5, false (IE9, Windows Vista):

```
var a,b;
alert(a=b=5);
alert(a>=b>=5);
```

I'm OK with the first, but both conditionals are true, so how come false?

If I try:

```
alert(a=b);
```

the alert is `undefined`.

Does JavaScript read from right to left here, i.e. b=5, a=b? But then the second alert should be true, as b>=5 is now true (=1), and a=5>=1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a >= b >= 5
```

is grouped as

```
(a >= b) >= 5
```

`a >= b` is true, which is converted to `1` when used in a numeric context. So this is equivalent to

```
1 >= 5
```

which is `false`.

If you want to do multiple comparisons, you should use:

```
alert(a >=b && b >= 5)
```

Comment: x is to be used in a numeric context

Comment: When `x` is a string, `x++` is `NaN`.

Comment: Try `x=true; alert(x++);`

Comment: Got it. Is 'false' numerically 0 universal, or are there inter-language issues

Comment: It's common to a number of languages: PHP, Javascript, C, C++.